# Should this still-off-topic edit to a closed off-topic question be rolled back?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, specific-edit

[Does VS Code have language extension for Apache Groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45538574/438992)

It's not clear to me how the edit got approved (or has value) since it's still off-topic AFAIK, and is more of a complaint/observation than anything else.

Should this be rolled back, or does it really matter?

Comment: It was [approved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/31329830) by the post owner. The "Editorial note" reads very much like meta commentary. I don't think it fixes the post to make it on topic.

Comment: As been pointed out it was approved by the author but the edit won't result in the question being reopened, so it's fine, that the edit was approved by the author of the question itself.